# How to create an multidimensional array with two types

Tags: swift

I have to create an array with two values.

This array has to be two values ( String and Integer)

How did I have to create the empty array and append new values?

Thx all for you help.

This is what I need.

```
var myData = [ ["1": 15], ["2" : 30], ["3": 15], ["4" : 30] ]
```

Comment: what the real problem? `myData` isn't an answer?

Comment: You should read about the difference between array, tuple, dictionary and set. And when we will use it.

Comment: The question is: How to declare a empty Array? and How to append new values that I get exact the structure in the example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This keyword of this topic array Dictionary.
You should create array dictionary follow this syntax:

```
var testData:  [[String: Int]] = []
let data_1 = ["1" : 15]
let data_2 = ["2" : 30]
let data_3 = ["3" : 15]
let data_4 = ["4" : 30]
```

You can add array into array:

```
testData.append(contentsOf: [data_1, data_2, data_3, data_4])
```

Or You can add every element into array:

```
testData.append(data_1)
testData.append(data_2)
testData.append(data_3)
testData.append(data_4)
```

You can read more about Collection Types in swift:

> https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/CollectionTypes.html

Answer (score 1):

Why not array of tuples?

```
var data : [(String, Int)] = [("1", 15),
                              ("2", 30),
                              ("3", 15),
                              ("4", 30)]

data.append(("5", 50))

let value = data[0]
let yourString = value.0 // "1"
let yourInteger = value.1 // 15
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work

```
var myData = [Dictionary<String:Int>]()
```